# Tensorflow warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I installed tensorflow library and while starting Hello world project like this:

```
> Found device 0 with properties:  name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major: 6
> minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7085 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
> totalMemory: 6.00GiB freeMemory: 4.96GiB 2018-02-10 19:30:15.740626: I
> C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1195]
> Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name:
> GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability:
> 6.1) b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
> 
> Process finished with exit code 0
```

II want to understand whether my videocard is actualy being used? I mean is everything ok with my installation result or only CPU is used due to this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a warning message that's the expected output, Tensorflow found your gpu and is using it. If it was using cpu it would mention /device:CPU:0